# Setting a comma in a excel file does not work

Tags: c#, excel, string

"," does not work when i type it in a excel cell

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[2 + i, 4].Value2 = products.ShopCategoryId2[i] + "," + products.ShopCategoryId3[i];
```

Desired output is "8888","8888"

Added colon for understanding that the numbers are strings

i am getting "888888888"

Comment: How do you mean it does not work? It does not appear in Excel? What is the desired output and what is the current output?

Comment: Also, What are the types of `products.ShopCategoryId2[i]` and `products.ShopCategoryId3[i]`?

Comment: both of theese are string lists and i added desired output and what i am getting

Comment: It may be some formatting that excel is applying. Does `string.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\"", products.ShopCategoryId2[i], products.ShopCategoryId3[i]);` work?

Comment: i think it is working though now im getting "8888","8888" and in my test i wrote that that is what i whant but it was written with the "" to just show that it was strings so what i actually whant is 8888,8888 and how do i get rid of the ""

Comment: I've added an answer which should solve it. Basically you need to remove the `\"` characters from my previous comment.

Comment: How about setting the cell format to text first? `xlWorkSheet.Cells[2 + i, 4].NumberFormat="@";`

Comment: Thank you for the answer @LocEngineer this one worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to the number formatting caused by Excel. It can be solved by adjusting the `NumberFormat` property...

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[2 + i, 4].NumberFormat = "@";
```

Then it should work.

If you're using C# 6 and above, you can use string interpolation for setting the value...

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[2 + i, 4].Value2 = $"{products.ShopCategoryId2[i]},{products.ShopCategoryId3[i]}";
```

Comment: this does not work this is really weird cuz the other one you showed me did

Comment: What is the new output using this answer?

Comment: same as the above with ur first example testing the second now

Comment: second alternative gives the same answer

Comment: Found the issue. Was caused by `NumberFormat` not being set initially to take the value as a raw string. Looks like a comment by @LocEngineer got there a few seconds before me!

Comment: Checking it but if its correct how do i give him a checkmark so other people will now what the answer was should i just answer my own question with his answer?

Comment: Marking my answer as accepted is the best way to let future people know what the answer was. Might also be worth upvoting his comment and thanking him, in the original comments on your question :)